# KeyError while building multidimensional dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build a dictionary with two keys but am getting a KeyError when assigning items.  I don't get the error when using each of the keys separately, and the syntax seems pretty straightforward so I'm stumped.

```
searchIndices = ['Books', 'DVD']
allProducts = {}
for index in searchIndices:
    res = amazon.ItemSearch(Keywords = entity, SearchIndex = index, ResponseGroup = 'Large', ItemPage = 1, Sort = "salesrank", Version = '2010-11-01')
    products = feedparser.parse(res)
    for x in range(10):
        allProducts[index][x] = { 'price' : products['entries'][x]['formattedprice'],  
                                  'url'   : products['entries'][x]['detailpageurl'], 
                                  'title' : products['entries'][x]['title'], 
                                  'img'   : products['entries'][x]['href'],
                                  'rank'  : products['entries'][x]['salesrank'] 
                                }
```

I don't believe the issue lies with feedparser (which converts xml to dict) or with the results I'm getting from amazon, as I have no issues building a dict when either using 'allProducts[x]' or 'allProducts[index]', but not both.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to assign to `allProducts[index][x]`, first a lookup is done on `allProducts[index]` to get a dict, then the value you're assigning is stored at index `x` in that dict.

However, the first time through the loop, `allProducts[index]` doesn't exist yet. Try this:

```
for x in range(10):
    if index not in allProducts:
        allProducts[index] = {  }    # or dict() if you prefer
    allProducts[index][x] = ...
```

Since you know all the indices that are supposed to be in `allProducts` in advance, you can initialize it before hand like this instead:

```
map(lambda i: allProducts[i] = {  }, searchIndices)
for index in searchIndices:
    # ... rest of loop does not need to be modified
```

Comment: Beautiful, I'm new to Python and forget that it doesn't autovivify.  Will register and upvote you, thanks!

Comment: @tippytop: Thanks, glad to have helped (you can click the checkmark outline under the vote count to mark my answer as accepted). Since you're new to Python (you sound like a Perl programmer ;-) ) you might not know the difference between `range` and `xrange` -- `range` creates a list of all the numbers (in memory), while `xrange` creates an iterator that generates the numbers one by one. In this case, `range` is OK since you're only creating a small list, but `xrange` is generally preferable.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Python 2.5 or later, then this kind of situation is tailor made for `collections.defaultdict`.

Simply replace the line:

```
allProducts = {}
```

With the following:

```
import collections
allProducts = collections.defaultdict(dict)
```

An example of this in use:

```
>>> import collections
>>> searchIndices = ['Books', 'DVD']
>>> allProducts = collections.defaultdict(dict)
>>> for idx in searchIndices:
...   print idx, allProducts[idx]
...
Books {}
DVD {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [setdefault](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method of the dictionary.

```
for x in range(10):
        allProducts.setdefault(index, {})[x] = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell python it's an dict inside a dict. It has no idea that allProducts[index] should be another dictionary.

You need to add lines like this whenever you're trying to do this (or use a defaultdict):

```
allProducts = {}
for index in searchIndices:
    allProducts[index] = {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
searchIndices = ['Books', 'DVD']
allProducts = {}
for index in searchIndices:
    res = amazon.ItemSearch(Keywords = entity, SearchIndex = index, ResponseGroup = 'Large', ItemPage = 1, Sort = "salesrank", Version = '2010-11-01')
    products = feedparser.parse(res)
    for x in range(10):
        if not allProducts.has_key(index):
            allProducts[index] = {}
        allProducts[index][x] = { 'price' : products['entries'][x]['formattedprice'],  
                                  'url'   : products['entries'][x]['detailpageurl'], 
                                  'title' : products['entries'][x]['title'], 
                                  'img'   : products['entries'][x]['href'],
                                  'rank'  : products['entries'][x]['salesrank'] 
                                }
```